# Django appends white space to views

Tags: python, django

So I have recently started looking into the Django framework, but it appends some white space in the top of my views even though the layout.html and layout.css is the same for each view.

layout.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    {% load staticfiles %} 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'layout.css' %}" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="navbar">
            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Homepage.</a>
            <a href="{% url 'home:index' %}" class="navbar-item">Home</a>
            <a href="{% url 'projects:index' %}" class="navbar-item">Projects</a>
            <a href="{% url 'home:about' %}" class="navbar-item">About</a>
        </div>

        <div class="text">
        {% block stuff %} 
        {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my views

```
def index(request):
return render(
    request,
    'home/index.html',
    {
        'greetings': "Welcome to my site!",
    }
)

def about(request): 
return render(
    request,
    'home/about.html',
    {
        'greetings': "Welcome to my site!",
    }
)
```

home/index.html and home/about.html both look like

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block stuff %}
{{ greetings }}
{% endblock %}
```

[about page pushed down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AHpi.png)

As seen in the image the view for the about.html page is push down, and I really cannot figure out why.

After inspecting the elements I found that for the about page, the header is added to the body tag.

[inspecting the elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYCNe.png)

Anyone who can help me out?

Comment: You should really look at the source HTML in your browser to debug this. Django does not add whitespace (well, template code adds a lot of whitespace, but browsers ignore whitespace), so most likely the issue is your css.

Comment: I have done that, and the source html files appears to be completely identical

Comment: How does `class="text"` affect the css? If you're using a `white-space: pre` on your div, all whitespace will be preserved. As said, template tags do add whitespace which won't be visible in normal divs, but will be visible in a `pre` block.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because of **CSS**. To find out where the space is coming from, click on **inspect element** and choose **select an element to inspect it**. Then slightly move the mouse around the page until you find that space and click on it. You can then find out where the space is coming from in the Styles tab.

Also make sure there are no `<br>`tags in your html template

Answer (score 0):

The view is certainly not the culprit here, it's just a python function which takes in a request and returns a response. The HTML looks fine too, check your **CSS** once again(or post it here) or you can always check the source code on your browser and **inspect element** the page through the Developer tools to check where the whitespace is coming from.

Comment: After inspecting the elements, it seems that Django has appended some text and the header inside the body tag, see image in updated question.